# Movie where a guy can see what is going to happen in next 2 minutes

Tags: identify-this-movie

I was watching a movie on a local cable channel, which doesn't display the name of the movie until the end.

The movie was about a guy who has some power to see what is going to happen in the next 2 minutes(if I am not wrong). There was a scene in which he saw a vision of a bullet coming and then he escaped from the bullet. At the end, he saved the city from some nuclear explosion

Comment: As I recall at the end he didn't save the city, I think his last line was something along the lines of "I made a mistake" then he goes back.....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ya I have seen it. You are certainly talking about [Next](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next_%282007_film%29). The main actor is [Nicolas Cage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Cage). He can see the next two minutes. As he could see the future, he could dodge the bullet. He also saved the city from nuclear explosion.

[image]